# Flickraw & VCR give unexpected results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, flickr, vcr

I´m using [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to test a method which gets a list of photosets from Flickr

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Photoset, type: :model do
  # ...
  describe '.import' do
    it "gets photosets" do
      VCR.use_cassette('photosets_getList') do
        expect(Photoset.import(user_id: ENV['FLICKR_TEST_USER_ID']).first).to be_a Photoset
      end
    end

    it "sets title" do
      VCR.use_cassette('photosets_getList') do
        expect(Photoset.import(user_id: ENV['FLICKR_TEST_USER_ID']).first.title).to eq 'Showcase'
      end
    end

    it "sets uid" do
      VCR.use_cassette('photosets_getList') do
        expect(Photoset.import(user_id: ENV['FLICKR_TEST_USER_ID']).first.uid).to eq '72157647753138397'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The method itself is pretty straight forward and uses flickraw to get the photos from
`flickr.photosets.getList` and them maps to `Photoset` objects.

```
class Photoset
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title, type: String
  field :uid, type: String

  validates_uniqueness_of :uid
  belongs_to :user

  # Get photosets from Flickr
  # @param [Hash] opts
  # @return [Enumerable]
  def self.import(opts = {})
    res = flickr.photosets.getList(opts)
    res.map do |item|
      new(
          uid: item["id"],
          title: item["title"]
      )
    end
  end
end
```

**However the specs fail intermittently as Flickraw also does a request to `flickr.reflection.getMethods` and**

```
flickr.photosets.getList(opts).map { |x| x }
```

**Sometimes returns the request methods instead of Photosets**

```
[("flickr.activity.userComments", "flickr.activity.userPhotos", "flickr.auth.checkToken"...]
```

**Am I using VCR wrong or is this a bug in Flickraw?**

These are the recorded HTTP interactions:

```
---
http_interactions:
- request:
    method: post
    uri: https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/
    body:
      encoding: US-ASCII
      string: method=flickr.reflection.getMethods&format=json&nojsoncallback=1
    headers:
      Accept-Encoding:
      - gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
      Accept:
      - "*/*"
      User-Agent:
      - FlickRaw/0.9.8
      Content-Type:
      - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  response:
    status:
      code: 200
      message: OK
    headers:
      Date:
      - Mon, 30 Mar 2015 14:57:38 GMT
      Content-Type:
      - application/json
      Content-Length:
      - '1428'
      P3p:
      - policyref="http://info.yahoo.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV
        TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY
        ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC GOV"
      Cache-Control:
      - private
      X-Served-By:
      - www235.flickr.bf1.yahoo.com
      Vary:
      - Accept-Encoding
      Age:
      - '0'
      Via:
      - http/1.1 fts124.flickr.bf1.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer/4.0.2 [cMsSf ]),
        http/1.1 r05.ycpi.dea.yahoo.net (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ])
      Server:
      - ATS
      Strict-Transport-Security:
      - max-age=259200
      Connection:
      - keep-alive
    body:
      encoding: UTF-8
      string: '{"methods":{"method":[{"_content":"flickr.activity.userComments"},{"_content":"flickr.activity.userPhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.auth.checkToken"},{"_content":"flickr.auth.getFrob"},{"_content":"flickr.auth.getFullToken"},{"_content":"flickr.auth.getToken"},{"_content":"flickr.auth.oauth.checkToken"},{"_content":"flickr.auth.oauth.getAccessToken"},{"_content":"flickr.blogs.getList"},{"_content":"flickr.blogs.getServices"},{"_content":"flickr.blogs.postPhoto"},{"_content":"flickr.cameras.getBrandModels"},{"_content":"flickr.cameras.getBrands"},{"_content":"flickr.collections.getInfo"},{"_content":"flickr.collections.getTree"},{"_content":"flickr.commons.getInstitutions"},{"_content":"flickr.contacts.getList"},{"_content":"flickr.contacts.getListRecentlyUploaded"},{"_content":"flickr.contacts.getPublicList"},{"_content":"flickr.contacts.getTaggingSuggestions"},{"_content":"flickr.favorites.add"},{"_content":"flickr.favorites.getContext"},{"_content":"flickr.favorites.getList"},{"_content":"flickr.favorites.getPublicList"},{"_content":"flickr.favorites.remove"},{"_content":"flickr.galleries.addPhoto"},{"_content":"flickr.galleries.create"},{"_content":"flickr.galleries.editMeta"},{"_content":"flickr.galleries.editPhoto"},{"_content":"flickr.galleries.editPhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.galleries.getInfo"},{"_content":"flickr.galleries.getList"},{"_content":"flickr.galleries.getListForPhoto"},{"_content":"flickr.galleries.getPhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.browse"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.discuss.replies.add"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.discuss.replies.delete"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.discuss.replies.edit"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.discuss.replies.getInfo"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.discuss.replies.getList"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.discuss.topics.add"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.discuss.topics.getInfo"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.discuss.topics.getList"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.getInfo"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.join"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.joinRequest"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.leave"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.members.getList"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.pools.add"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.pools.getContext"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.pools.getGroups"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.pools.remove"},{"_content":"flickr.groups.search"},{"_content":"flickr.interestingness.getList"},{"_content":"flickr.machinetags.getNamespaces"},{"_content":"flickr.machinetags.getPairs"},{"_content":"flickr.machinetags.getPredicates"},{"_content":"flickr.machinetags.getRecentValues"},{"_content":"flickr.machinetags.getValues"},{"_content":"flickr.panda.getList"},{"_content":"flickr.panda.getPhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.people.findByEmail"},{"_content":"flickr.people.findByUsername"},{"_content":"flickr.people.getGroups"},{"_content":"flickr.people.getInfo"},{"_content":"flickr.people.getLimits"},{"_content":"flickr.people.getPhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.people.getPhotosOf"},{"_content":"flickr.people.getPublicGroups"},{"_content":"flickr.people.getPublicPhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.people.getUploadStatus"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.addTags"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.comments.addComment"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.comments.deleteComment"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.comments.editComment"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.comments.getList"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.comments.getRecentForContacts"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.delete"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.geo.batchCorrectLocation"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.geo.correctLocation"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.geo.getLocation"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.geo.getPerms"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.geo.photosForLocation"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.geo.removeLocation"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.geo.setContext"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.geo.setLocation"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.geo.setPerms"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.getAllContexts"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.getContactsPhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.getContactsPublicPhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.getContext"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.getCounts"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.getExif"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.getFavorites"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.getInfo"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.getNotInSet"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.getPerms"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.getRecent"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.getSizes"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.getUntagged"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.getWithGeoData"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.getWithoutGeoData"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.licenses.getInfo"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.licenses.setLicense"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.notes.add"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.notes.delete"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.notes.edit"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.people.add"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.people.delete"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.people.deleteCoords"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.people.editCoords"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.people.getList"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.recentlyUpdated"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.removeTag"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.search"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.setContentType"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.setDates"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.setMeta"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.setPerms"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.setSafetyLevel"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.setTags"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.suggestions.approveSuggestion"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.suggestions.getList"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.suggestions.rejectSuggestion"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.suggestions.removeSuggestion"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.suggestions.suggestLocation"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.transform.rotate"},{"_content":"flickr.photos.upload.checkTickets"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.addPhoto"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.comments.addComment"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.comments.deleteComment"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.comments.editComment"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.comments.getList"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.create"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.delete"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.editMeta"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.editPhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.getContext"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.getInfo"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.getList"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.getPhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.orderSets"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.removePhoto"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.removePhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.reorderPhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.photosets.setPrimaryPhoto"},{"_content":"flickr.places.find"},{"_content":"flickr.places.findByLatLon"},{"_content":"flickr.places.getChildrenWithPhotosPublic"},{"_content":"flickr.places.getInfo"},{"_content":"flickr.places.getInfoByUrl"},{"_content":"flickr.places.getPlaceTypes"},{"_content":"flickr.places.getShapeHistory"},{"_content":"flickr.places.getTopPlacesList"},{"_content":"flickr.places.placesForBoundingBox"},{"_content":"flickr.places.placesForContacts"},{"_content":"flickr.places.placesForTags"},{"_content":"flickr.places.placesForUser"},{"_content":"flickr.places.resolvePlaceId"},{"_content":"flickr.places.resolvePlaceURL"},{"_content":"flickr.places.tagsForPlace"},{"_content":"flickr.prefs.getContentType"},{"_content":"flickr.prefs.getGeoPerms"},{"_content":"flickr.prefs.getHidden"},{"_content":"flickr.prefs.getPrivacy"},{"_content":"flickr.prefs.getSafetyLevel"},{"_content":"flickr.push.getSubscriptions"},{"_content":"flickr.push.getTopics"},{"_content":"flickr.push.subscribe"},{"_content":"flickr.push.unsubscribe"},{"_content":"flickr.reflection.getMethodInfo"},{"_content":"flickr.reflection.getMethods"},{"_content":"flickr.stats.getCollectionDomains"},{"_content":"flickr.stats.getCollectionReferrers"},{"_content":"flickr.stats.getCollectionStats"},{"_content":"flickr.stats.getCSVFiles"},{"_content":"flickr.stats.getPhotoDomains"},{"_content":"flickr.stats.getPhotoReferrers"},{"_content":"flickr.stats.getPhotosetDomains"},{"_content":"flickr.stats.getPhotosetReferrers"},{"_content":"flickr.stats.getPhotosetStats"},{"_content":"flickr.stats.getPhotoStats"},{"_content":"flickr.stats.getPhotostreamDomains"},{"_content":"flickr.stats.getPhotostreamReferrers"},{"_content":"flickr.stats.getPhotostreamStats"},{"_content":"flickr.stats.getPopularPhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.stats.getTotalViews"},{"_content":"flickr.tags.getClusterPhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.tags.getClusters"},{"_content":"flickr.tags.getHotList"},{"_content":"flickr.tags.getListPhoto"},{"_content":"flickr.tags.getListUser"},{"_content":"flickr.tags.getListUserPopular"},{"_content":"flickr.tags.getListUserRaw"},{"_content":"flickr.tags.getMostFrequentlyUsed"},{"_content":"flickr.tags.getRelated"},{"_content":"flickr.test.echo"},{"_content":"flickr.test.login"},{"_content":"flickr.test.null"},{"_content":"flickr.urls.getGroup"},{"_content":"flickr.urls.getUserPhotos"},{"_content":"flickr.urls.getUserProfile"},{"_content":"flickr.urls.lookupGallery"},{"_content":"flickr.urls.lookupGroup"},{"_content":"flickr.urls.lookupUser"}]},"stat":"ok"}'
    http_version: 
  recorded_at: Mon, 30 Mar 2015 14:57:37 GMT
- request:
    method: post
    uri: https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/
    body:
      encoding: US-ASCII
      string: user_id=62829091%40N05&method=flickr.photosets.getList&format=json&nojsoncallback=1
    headers:
      Accept-Encoding:
      - gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
      Accept:
      - "*/*"
      User-Agent:
      - FlickRaw/0.9.8
      Content-Type:
      - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  response:
    status:
      code: 200
      message: OK
    headers:
      Date:
      - Mon, 30 Mar 2015 14:57:38 GMT
      Content-Type:
      - application/json
      Content-Length:
      - '878'
      P3p:
      - policyref="http://info.yahoo.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV
        TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY
        ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC GOV"
      Cache-Control:
      - private
      X-Served-By:
      - www35.flickr.bf1.yahoo.com
      Vary:
      - Accept-Encoding
      Age:
      - '0'
      Via:
      - http/1.1 fts109.flickr.bf1.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer/4.0.2 [cMsSf ]),
        http/1.1 r14.ycpi.dea.yahoo.net (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ])
      Server:
      - ATS
      Strict-Transport-Security:
      - max-age=259200
      Connection:
      - keep-alive
    body:
      encoding: UTF-8
      string: '{"photosets":{"page":1,"pages":1,"perpage":10,"total":10,"photoset":[{"id":"72157647753138397","primary":"13362508473","secret":"73945d3830","server":"7300","farm":8,"photos":"10","videos":0,"title":{"_content":"Showcase"},"description":{"_content":""},"needs_interstitial":0,"visibility_can_see_set":1,"count_views":"0","count_comments":"0","can_comment":0,"date_create":"1411992696","date_update":"1420398843"},{"id":"72157642806447225","primary":"13362324935","secret":"792aed9e58","server":"7072","farm":8,"photos":"11","videos":0,"title":{"_content":"Offpistcamp,
        Mars 2014"},"description":{"_content":""},"needs_interstitial":0,"visibility_can_see_set":1,"count_views":"18","count_comments":"0","can_comment":0,"date_create":"1395604793","date_update":"1420398843"},{"id":"72157635592985815","primary":"9789159454","secret":"68e3687ebf","server":"7304","farm":8,"photos":"49","videos":0,"title":{"_content":"Sara
        & Adam\u00b4s wedding "},"description":{"_content":""},"needs_interstitial":0,"visibility_can_see_set":1,"count_views":"36","count_comments":"0","can_comment":0,"date_create":"1379447652","date_update":"1379448808"},{"id":"72157633225753747","primary":"8643524170","secret":"d31134cfac","server":"8387","farm":9,"photos":"11","videos":0,"title":{"_content":"\u00c5re
        Park"},"description":{"_content":""},"needs_interstitial":0,"visibility_can_see_set":1,"count_views":"0","count_comments":"0","can_comment":0,"date_create":"1365784604","date_update":"1365784720"},{"id":"72157632691639823","primary":"8446828475","secret":"c27f229c79","server":"8079","farm":9,"photos":"5","videos":0,"title":{"_content":"\u00c5resj\u00f6n"},"description":{"_content":""},"needs_interstitial":0,"visibility_can_see_set":1,"count_views":"0","count_comments":"0","can_comment":0,"date_create":"1360071999","date_update":"1360072052"},{"id":"72157632228500139","primary":"8266649775","secret":"bea16448f6","server":"8337","farm":9,"photos":"36","videos":0,"title":{"_content":"Renskiljning"},"description":{"_content":""},"needs_interstitial":0,"visibility_can_see_set":1,"count_views":"8","count_comments":"0","can_comment":0,"date_create":"1355334260","date_update":"1365536767"},{"id":"72157632141702707","primary":"8234153651","secret":"82b1bababb","server":"8487","farm":9,"photos":"11","videos":0,"title":{"_content":"Ozone
        Demodag 2012"},"description":{"_content":""},"needs_interstitial":0,"visibility_can_see_set":1,"count_views":"30","count_comments":"0","can_comment":0,"date_create":"1354372862","date_update":"1354373227"},{"id":"72157629510040228","primary":"6956421098","secret":"fe55925613","server":"7197","farm":8,"photos":"14","videos":0,"title":{"_content":"Slutskjutet
        p\u00e5 Skutskjutet"},"description":{"_content":""},"needs_interstitial":0,"visibility_can_see_set":1,"count_views":"4","count_comments":"0","can_comment":0,"date_create":"1335109758","date_update":"1335109926"},{"id":"72157626719466442","primary":"5719219791","secret":"5966d75b4d","server":"2128","farm":3,"photos":"4","videos":0,"title":{"_content":"Trondheim"},"description":{"_content":""},"needs_interstitial":0,"visibility_can_see_set":1,"count_views":"1","count_comments":"0","can_comment":0,"date_create":"1305400311","date_update":"1354372544"},{"id":"72157626594657331","primary":"5719668226","secret":"d5c9c6e1bd","server":"2593","farm":3,"photos":"15","videos":0,"title":{"_content":"Rope
        Swing Session"},"description":{"_content":"Oslo, norway"},"needs_interstitial":0,"visibility_can_see_set":1,"count_views":"8","count_comments":"0","can_comment":0,"date_create":"1305398192","date_update":"1305398195"}]},"stat":"ok"}'
    http_version: 
  recorded_at: Mon, 30 Mar 2015 14:57:38 GMT
recorded_with: VCR 2.9.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flickr.reflection.getMethods` is called to build all the objects and methods. Flickraw does not know what methods are available when initiallzed. If you want a deterministic behavior, you can use [flickraw-cached](https://rubygems.org/gems/flickraw-cached) which embeds a list of all methods.

https://github.com/hanklords/flickraw/issues/86#issuecomment-96834525